# How is tensorflow's Back propagation implemented ? (Memory problems)

Tags: memory-management, object-detection, tensorflow

I've started implementing a [fast-rcnn in TF](https://github.com/SamyMe/tensorflow-fast-rcnn) (VGG16 based). While doing my learning, I'm having memory issues if I try to back propagate over all layers. But test works good though. (I have a Gforce GTX 1060 with 6G of ram)

I was wondering how comes ? does TF saves require saving parameters twice for training ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of activations. During forward propagation, you only need to store the last layer of activations, so memory usage is independent of depth. To compute gradients you need to store activations for all layers, so memory cost grows with depth of network.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The memory problems in back propagation step can arise because:

> Each back propagation step takes approximately twice the memory and
>   compute time than the forward propagation step.

Taken from this [video](https://youtu.be/83bMCcPmFvE?t=1m38s), which also has a nice diagram explaining it.